# Magento Website Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

So I have moved my live website hosted on Magento 2.1.5 to a staging environment that has Magento 2.3.
I get this error now when I try to access the localhost.

Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

When I go to the exception log I have this error:
[2019-03-12 14:19:23] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Function mdecrypt_generic() is deprecated in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/f$
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php(152): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Function mdecry...', '/var/ww$

## 1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(317): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->decrypt('=\xAC\x8Fj')

## 2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(109): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('PayPal')

## 3 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->pro$

## 4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(88): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted\Interceptor->$

## 5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(106): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->$

## 6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite.php(34): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->proces$

## 7 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposit$

## 8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(102): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite\Proxy->process(Arr$

## 9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')

## 10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')

## 11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)

## 12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')

## 13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()

In therms of prerequesits for Magento 2.3 I have all the required stuff. when I did the fresh installation it was working, now that I moved the files from my existing live site, it has a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the upgrade to magneto 2.3 is not trivial. please list us what you have done in order to upgrade

Comment: Hi Phillip, basically I installed Magento 2.3 with php 7.2 and latest mariadb. And it was working. I was able to access Front page and Back page.
I then moved all root files of the Magento 2.1.5 website to the root directory on the Magento 2.3 server.
Imported the database from the 2.15 server to the 2.3 server with the exact same db user and password and privileges.
I have updated the secure and unsecure paths in the db tables
I have set the correct user ID and password in the env.php
I have updated the read and write permission son the var directory

Comment: also I have flushed the var/case and var/page_cach

Comment: that's not how you're supposed to upgrade magento2. please read more about how to upgrade magento. it's not that simple

Comment: hi Phillip I did read what I could find. Do you have any links for me to good instructions?

Comment: What did you read that suggested the steps you took?

Comment: Hi Phillipp, I followed the instrucions on Magento website on how to install it. I am a new to linux and magento so it took a while for me to get all the right things done. the steps I took installed the latest version of Mangeto by default.
I then found some information on this platform on what needs to be done to transfer a website from localhost to server so I assumed that it would work the same way if I transfer from server to localhost and I just change all urls to point to localhost.

Comment: Do you believe that I need to install on localhost Magento 2.1.5 which is the same on the live server and then later on update Magento? I have had plenty of practice now at the install stuff, I am happy to do that, I just wanted to see if i can get this working so I dont waste my time trying to downgrade to Magento 2.1.5.